# ConEmu disable Esc shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim, git, conemu

I'm having problems with ConEmu because of the Esc shortcut that hides the window. When I use something that makes use of Esc, such as Vim or `git commit`, an escape hides the window instead of removing focus and disabling current activity.

I already use `Ctrl+~` to hide the console. So I don't need that hotkey. How can I remove it?

If I go to Keys & Macros in settings, I find that shortcut, but it's disabled and cannot be changed at all!

Comment: What shortcut? Who can guess?

Comment: @Maximus the Esc shortcut?

Comment: The `Esc` is the **key**. I've asked you about **action** (hotkey description in the list) you try to modify.

Comment: @Maximus What I see in "Settings", in the "Keys & Macro" section, is a big list. In that list, there's a Hotkey that is "Esc", a Type that is "System", and a Description that is "Minimize ConEmu by Esc when no open consoles left...". I hope that answers your question. If not, let me know.

Comment: You said "when no open consoles left". Obviously, when you have vim, there is a console. So the shortcut is not triggered in your case.

Comment: @Maximus but this is the only shortcut associated with Esc! If I filter with "Esc", everything else is gone! Is this a bug?

Comment: @Maximus Hi there. Could you please look at this issue again and suggest solutions, since you're the developer of this software? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: ConEmu doesn't minimize on Esc when there is a console. Run `ConEmu -basic` to check.

Comment: @Maximus Your hint inspired me to hack into the config file, and I did, and fixed the problem (check the answer). Thanks. Also thanks for the great console too :) ... I love it!

Comment: ESC does hide the window, which gets me stuck in vim's edit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved the problem by modifying the config file manually. If one opens the "Settings" of the program, the first thing that appears is a path to a file called "storage", which is an XML file.

There, I found the line:

```
<value name="Multi.MinByEsc" type="hex" data="01"/>
```

and changed it to:

```
<value name="Multi.MinByEsc" type="hex" data="00"/>
```

And that solved the problem.